# Create contour from scratch in python OpenCV (cv2)

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to use the opencv python interface cv2 to determine if a polygon is convex. From all I found on the web, the input contour must be a numpy array of float32 tuples for each point. So I assumed it to work like this:

```
import cv2, numpy
contour = numpy.array( [ 
(378, 949), (375, 940), (368, 934), 
(359, 932), (350, 937), (345, 955), 
(351, 962), (359, 966), (368, 964), 
(376, 958) ], numpy.float32 )
cv2.isContourConvex(contour)
```

But I get this error:

`OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (The matrix can not be converted to point sequence because of inappropriate element type) in cvPointSeqFromMat, file /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/utils.cpp, line 59`

Can anyone tell me what element type would be appropriate and how to therefore create a contour from scratch?

Comment: Guess: You may want to change the dtype from float to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the openCV installation on debian testing. After installing openCV 2.4.8 from source, it works.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV expects that the points of an image would be integer tuples, just change their type to int:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> contour = np.array([(378, 949), (375, 940), (368, 934), (359, 932), 
... (350, 937), (345, 955), (351, 962), (359, 966), (368, 964), 
... (376, 958) ], dtype=np.int)
>>> cv2.isContourConvex(contour)
 True
```

Comment: I already tried this before, but it leads to this error: Assertion failed (contour.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (contour.depth() == CV_32F || contour.depth() == CV_32S)) in isContourConvex, file /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 1737