# Convert cv2.minAreaRect() output to contour for input to cv2.boundingRect()

Tags: python, opencv

I've already tried a number of approaches to create a boundingRect() around a minAreaRect(), but I keep running into an error. I could simply use the original contour yes, but at this point it's a matter of understanding why a contour that works with cv2.isContourConvex() and cv2.drawContours() won't work with cv2.boundingRect(). Basically I'm trying to better understand the construction of a contour.

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# EX1: draw contour from minAreaRect() output
mar = cv2.minAreaRect( contour )
pts = cv2.cv.BoxPoints( mar )
pts_contour = np.int0(pts)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [pts_contour], 0, 255, -1)

cv2.boundingRect( pts_contour )  # ERROR: see below

# EX2: test contour convex
contour = np.array([(378, 949), (375, 940), (368, 934), 
    (359, 932), (350, 937), (345, 955), (351, 962), (359, 966), (368, 964),
    (376, 958) ], dtype=np.int)
print cv2.isContourConvex(contour)

cv2.boundingRect( contour )  # ERROR: see below
```

EX1: Error from boundingRect(): OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (The image/matrix format is not supported by the function) in cvBoundingRect
  This example of converting to a contour was provided in the [Rotated Rectangles section here](http://opencvpython.blogspot.it/2012/06/contours-2-brotherhood.html)

EX2: Error from boundingRect(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (points.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (points.depth() == CV_32F || points.depth() == CV_32S)) in boundingRect
  This example of creating a contour from scratch [was provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928944/create-contour-from-scratch-in-python-opencv-cv2)

Again I can accomplish my goals so I don't want suggestions on workarounds, but I would instead like to better understand the construct behind the contour and the error itself because I could see it being useful to create a boundingRect() from selected points

Also, I don't know if it matters but I've noticed that there is a difference between the output from BoxPoints() and findContours()[0]:

```
# BoxPoints:
[[1051 1367]
[ 968 1364]
[ 977 1072]
[1061 1074]]

# findCountours()[0]:
[[[ 992 1073]]
[[ 991 1074]]
[[ 989 1074]]
[[ 988 1073]]]

>>> cv2.__version__
'2.4.9'
```

cv2.boxPoints() is not available to me so I'm not sure if that would net me different results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One detail in **EX2** is explicit in opencv error message: it is expecting an array of `dtype` float32 or int32 : `(points.depth() == CV_32F || points.depth() == CV_32S)`. (tested with numpy v19, which if I were to guess you're not using since I couldn't find `int0`)

As for EX1, I'm sorry I can't reproduce it with opencv 3.0.0-beta (the cv2.cv is gone). By the way may I suggest not spending too much time wondering about this part of the library : cv2.cv is a [legacy feature](http://answers.opencv.org/question/22465/whats-the-difference-between-cv-and-cv2-using/).

Comment: So I fixed the dtype error, I should've caught that but I was about at the end of my rope at that point. When I feed that to cv2.isContourConvex() everything is good. I also gave it as input to cv2.minAreaRect() no problem. However, cv2.boundingRect() now gives the same error as ex1 for ex2.fixed. Any thoughts on why one function accepts this format as Points data but another doesn't?

Comment: My take is that some functions require a deeper data type if they perform sums (otherwise the values can overflow), or require a float data type if they use fractions (eg. accumulateWeighted)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like this:
(x,y,w,h)=cv2.boundingRect( pts_contour )
It returns a tuple when you use this function.